# How to set the VSCode use tab switch the suggest?

Tags: visual-studio-code

the default setting of tab is  use current suggest...
but I want to use tab switch  to the next suggest and complement and use shift+tab to the previous suggest,use Enter  select current suggest...
What should I do to achieve this keymap?
My VSC version is 1.50.1 and I use vim keymap....

Comment: Also here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48097507/visual-studio-code-use-tab-instead-of-arrow-keys-to-select-intellisense-sugge/48098133#48098133

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done with the help of the `when` clause by adding this to your `keybindings.json`:

```json
{
    "key": "tab",
    "command": "selectNextSuggestion",
    "when": "suggestWidgetVisible && suggestWidgetMultipleSuggestions"
}
```

This way the binding won't affect the behaviour of Tab when there are no suggestions shown (i.e. when editing text, of course depending on what the vim keybindings override); it will still insert the suggestion if it's only one (since `suggestWidgetMultipleSuggestions` will evaluate to false; if you want consistency, just remove it from the `when` clause, leaving only `suggestWidgetVisible` there).

Similar thing for `Shift+Tab`:

```json
{
    "key": "shift+tab",
    "command": "selectPrevSuggestion",
    "when": "suggestWidgetVisible && suggestWidgetMultipleSuggestions"
}
```

`Enter` shouldn't need to be overridden, but if for some reason it does, it should go like this:

```json
{
    "key": "enter",
    "command": "acceptSelectedSuggestion",
    "when": "suggestWidgetVisible"
}
```

Details about `when` directives can be found [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_when-clause-contexts).