# VSCode - Disable up/down keys from navigating suggestions

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image]

In VSCode, I have disabled the `Editor: Accept Suggestions On Enter` setting. This means I must use TAB to accept suggestions, and use ENTER for what it's meant for - to start a newline.

I'd like to do the same thing for the arrow keys. Normally they will navigate up/down the suggestion box, but I'd rather that they consistently navigate my code instead. I'd prefer to use TAB and SHIFT+TAB for navigating the suggestions box.

Is there such a setting to accomplish this in VSCode?

Note, I would *not* like to disable the suggestions box altogether, just change how you navigate it.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/48098133/836330  I haven't tested it for the situation where <kbd>Tab</kbd> will also accept suggestions - seems that will conflict with using <kbd>Tab</kbd> to navigate the suggestions as well.

Comment: @Mark Thanks I'll try that out! I forgot Tab for navigation conflicts with Tab for accepting suggestions, my bad.