# customizing autocomplete keys

Tags: visual-studio-code, autocomplete, keyboard-shortcuts

When an autocomplete suggestion list appears, I want the arrow keys to still move the cursor around (as if the autocomplete list wasn't there). This would cancel the autocomplete.

I would like to use other keys for *list up/down* and *list select* (eg: <kbd>kp4</kbd> & <kbd>kp1</kbd> for *up/down*, <kbd>tab</kbd> and <kbd>kp0</kbd> for *select*).

Is this possible?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/48098133/836330

Comment: @Mark That link solved it - this is almost a dupe except it uses different terms (intellisense vs autocomplete) so I didn't see it. Do you want to make that into an answer?

Comment: No, I think it is close enough to a dupe but I would appreciate an upvote there.